# Count of unique values in an excel sheet

Tags: excel-2007

I have an excel sheet with  values in them . I would like to know if their is a way if I could just give me the count of all unique values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of unique number values in cells A:A, but do not count blank cells or text values

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0,1))
```

Count the number of unique text and number values in cells A:A , but do not count blank cells or text values

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A:A)>0,MATCH(A:A,A:A,0),""), IF(LEN(A:A)>0,MATCH(A:A,A:A,0),""))>0,1))
```

### UPDATE:

```
Number List Unique Count
234         1
34          2
44          1
4           1
57          1
5           2
            0
45          2
34          2
45          2
5           2
3           1
            0
22          1
```

Place this formula on the top and drag down to get count of each number

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works for me . Eg. I have values like 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4. The list goes on . I want a count of how many 1's and 2's and so on I have.

Comment: @Senthil: You mean individual number count

Comment: Yes the individual count number for each unique value.Like how many no. of 1's and 2's and 3's and so on.

Comment: Thanks .It does help me . What I did was create a pivot table and add the row and value  fields which gives me the exact count.